# Javascript reliance an issue for mobile optimised sites?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm mobile optimising a site with media queries. As I understand mobile browsers are generally quite modern and can handle CSS3 etc well. So does this mean javascript reliance for the mobile version isn't too much of a problem?

I know how to find stats on desktop users with no js, are the same stats available for mobile usage? Thanks

Comment: JavaScript reliance is always a problem, your website is made of HTML & CSS that should work. JS is bells and whistles.

Comment: Well 'reliant' is overstating the case, the site will still work. Im just wondering how likely it is a mobile browser will respect conditional stylesheets but not js. Thanks

Comment: smartphones (android, iphone) behave other phones are less pleasant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Raynos said, Andriod devices and iPhones/iPads are just fine.

You can even use jquery mobile in order to take advantage of events that exists only in mobile devices, like touch, tap, rotate...

Relying heavily on javascript is never recommended however, ie, your website should work with only HTML and CSS. With less features, effects, but should work.

Another point to observe is that many mobile devices uses opera mobile/mini. Opera plays nice with javascript. So, the number of mobile devices with absolute no javascript support is decreasing day after day.

Comment: The trick, imo, is to differentiate between smartphones (including tablets, set-top-boxes, etc) and feature-phones (WAP/WML/iMode). If you're only focusing on smartphones (which generally have desktop-capable browsers), then like you said, JavaScript isn't a problem. If you also want to create content for feature-phones, then you will need to do significant work to make an alternate version anyway.